# INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, cannot specify Id in an insert call: [Id] (TEST)

Tags: apex, unit-test

I've been trying to create a pretty simple trigger. The trigger works however I'm having trouble getting the test right. I'm not a salesforcAny thoughts

**Trigger:**

```
trigger SubscriptionLinx on Linx__c (before insert) {

String email;
String prioritylevel;

for(Linx__c obj: Trigger.new)
{      
    {
        email = obj.Creator_Email__c;
        prioritylevel = obj.Priority_Level__c;
                       }

List<Subscription__c> subscription = [SELECT id, Creator_Email__c FROM Subscription__c WHERE Creator_Email__c =: email];

if(subscription.size() > 0)

{
    obj.Priority_Level__c = 'Paying Customer';      
}

}

}
```

**Test Class**
@isTest

```
/*
* Tests
*/

/*
 * This is the basic test
 */

public with sharing class TestSubscriptionLinx { 


 public static final String NAME = 'Expert';
 public static final String EMAIL = 'tuser15@salesforce.com';

static testMethod void basicTest() {

    Subscription__c testsubscription = new Subscription__c(Name = 'Expert', Creator_Email__c = 'tuser15@salesforce.com');
    insert testsubscription;

    Contact testcontact = new Contact(LastName = 'TestContact', Email = 'tuser15@salesforce.com', User_ID__c = '123Test');
    insert testsubscription;

    List<Contact> NewContact = [select id, User_ID__c FROM Contact where User_ID__c=:'123Test']; 

    Account testcompany = new Account(Name = 'TestCompany', Company_ID_del__c = '123Test' );
    insert testcompany;

    List<Account> NewCompany = [select id, Company_ID_del__c FROM Account where Company_ID_del__c=:'123Test']; 

    Linx__c testlinx = new Linx__c(Name='Test Linx', Company__c = 'NewCompany.id', Linx_Id__c = '123Test', Powerlinx_User__c = 'NewContact.id' );
     insert testlinx;

    List<Linx__c> NewLinx = [select id, Priority_Level__c, Linx_Id__c FROM Linx__c where Linx_Id__c=:'123Test']; 

    for (Linx__c l : NewLinx){
    //   System.assertEquals(aLead.ActivityHistories[0].subject, 'Email: '+SUBJECT);


        System.assertEquals(l.Priority_Level__c, 'Paying Customer');

    }

}}
```

Comment: Also, there is a mistype in your test class. In line 10, you have added **insert testsubscription;** instead of **insert testcontact;**

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate issue (the error message in your subject) is caused by the 4th (non-blank) line in basicTest, you are calling `insert testsubscription;` a second time.  This is trying to insert the same record you inserted in the 2nd line again, only now it has an id (as a result of the first insert), hence the error.  I believe you meant for that to be `insert testcontact;`.

However, you have a larger issue; your trigger code is not properly bulkified.  Specifically, you are running a soql query inside a for loop; that for loop can have up to 200 records in it.  The first time you need to bulk insert >100 Linx__c objects, you are going to get an error about too many queries.  Even if you don't intend to bulk load these records, you should still properly bulkify the code.  The system can merge concurrent requests into a single trigger invocation; other triggers can fire, etc.  I suggest you read the [entire section on triggers in the Force.com Developer Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers.htm), but [this page on bulk trigger best practices](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_bestpract.htm) is a good place to start.

Here's how i'd rewrite your trigger to run only a single query, regardless of the number of records passed to the trigger:

```
trigger SubscriptionLinx on Linx__c (before insert) {

//get set of all email addresses to be checked    
set<string> emails = new set<string>();
for(Linx__c obj: Trigger.new) {      
    emails.add(obj.Creator_Email__c);
}

//get set of email addresses that have subscriptions
set<string> subscriptionEmails = new set<string>()
for(Subscription__c subscription : [SELECT id, Creator_Email__c FROM Subscription__c WHERE Creator_Email__c in :emails]) {
    subscriptionEmails.add(subscription.Creator_Email__c);
}

//check each Linx object and update if needed
for(Linx__c obj: Trigger.new) {  
    string email = obj.Creator_Email__c;
    if (subscriptionEmails.contains(email) {
        obj.Priority_Level__c = 'Paying Customer';
    }
}

}
```

*please excuse any typos, I have not run this in an org.

Answer (score 0):

In your test class you have NewCompany.Id and NewContact.Id in quotes so it's not parsing right.

```
Linx__c testlinx = new Linx__c(Name='Test Linx', Company__c = 'NewCompany.id', Linx_Id__c = '123Test', Powerlinx_User__c = 'NewContact.id' );
```

should be more like

```
Linx__c testlinx = new Linx__c(Name='Test Linx', Company__c = NewCompany.id, Linx_Id__c = '123Test', Powerlinx_User__c = NewContact.id );
```